# Python don't remove return cartridge and feed line in file

Tags: python, hash, md5, strip

I am trying to build the MD5 hash based on a txt file. However, there are some rules that I need to follow, such as:

- The encoding rule must be 'ISO-8859-1'
- All the characters must be lowercase
- **New line characters and carriage return characters must NOT be considered on hash building**

  My file contains `\r` and `\n` characters, which means New line and Return Cartridge. I've tried remove this characters using `rstrip` and `strip` functions, but it looks that didn't work. To be sure about this, I wrote a txt file and opened it on Notepad++ and, as you can see on the picture below, the characters still there.

[Check the cr and lf characters in that image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaPVN.png)

I tried another solution: I used `split` function to create a list, using `\n` as a delimiter, just to be sure if that characters are really in there. As I thought, they were.

What should I do to really remove that characters?

One of the codes I tried:

```
from hashlib import md5

open_file = open('N0003977.290', 'r', encoding = 'ISO-8859-1')
test_file = open('file_test.txt', 'w')
file_content = open_file.read().lower().rstrip('\n\r ').strip('\n\r')

#writing a txt file to check if there are new line characters
test_file.write(file_content)
test_file.close()

#creating a md5 hash
m = md5()
m.update(file_content.encode('ISO-8859-1'))
print(m.hexdigest())
```

Comment: Use `str.replace` in order to replace those characters with an empty string, i.e. `file_content.replace('\n', '').replace('\r', '')`.

Comment: I tried that too, but it didn't work. :/

Comment: how did it not work?

Comment: The characters wasn't replaced. Check the picture above to see the characters on notepad++, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would delete the "carriage return" and "line feed" characters using [`str.translate()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate), like so:

```
file_content = file_content.translate({ord(ch):None for ch in '\r\n'})
```

Alternatively, if this were a classroom assignment and we had not yet covered `str.translate()`, I might do the work "by hand":

```
file_content = ''.join(ch for ch in file_content if ch not in '\r\n')
```

Complete program:

```
from hashlib import md5

open_file = open('N0003977.290', 'r', encoding = 'ISO-8859-1')
test_file = open('file_test.txt', 'w', encoding = 'ISO-8859-1')
file_content = open_file.read()

# Choose one of the following:
file_content = file_content.translate({ord(ch):None for ch in '\r\n'})
# file_content = ''.join(ch for ch in file_content if ch not in '\r\n')


#writing a txt file to check if there are new line characters
test_file.write(file_content)
test_file.close()

#creating a md5 hash
m = md5()
m.update(file_content.encode('ISO-8859-1'))
print(m.hexdigest())
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the original file in ISO-8859-1 encoding?

If it is, you should not encode it before hashing, otherwise you should do the encode but not open the file using this encode.

The rstrip and lstrip will not work, because it is escaping only at the beginning and end of the entire content:

`>>> '\r\nlalala\r\nlalalal\r\n'.rstrip().lstrip()
'lalala\r\nlalalal'`

Hope it helps you,